# What is the correct way to use MySql Case statement

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying this:

```
CASE VAR_DIVISION WHEN 'C3' OR 'J4' THEN
    /* code here */
End Case
```

But I keep getting errors when I try to execute the procedure.

Comment: Is that the full statement? Where is the `FROM TableName` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is the `End Case` - it just needs to be `end`, followed by a column name - like so:

```
CASE VAR_DIVISION WHEN 'C3' OR 'J4' THEN
    /* code here */
End column_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
remove case from End case
//and add
END as column_name
```